# Unable to send Platform Event to Salesforce CRM from Kafka Cloud Confluent thorugh Kafka Salesforce Platform Event Sink Connector

Tags: kafka

I am trying to send a topic record to Kafka Cloud Confluent with POSTMAN, using Kafka Confluent REST Api. Then, I want to publish a Platform Event on Salesforce CRM using Kafka Salesforce Platform Event Sink Connector.

[image]

This is the event received on Kafka:

[image]

But unfortunately, event message is going into DLQ (Dead Letter Queue). This is the stack trace produced by Kafka Cloud:

---

{
"key": "__connect.errors.topic",
"stringValue": "test_topic"
},
{
"key": "__connect.errors.partition",
"stringValue": "5"
},
{
"key": "__connect.errors.offset",
"stringValue": "30"
},
{
"key": "__connect.errors.connector.name",
"stringValue": "lcc-vrw8nz"
},
{
"key": "__connect.errors.task.id",
"stringValue": "0"
},
{
"key": "__connect.errors.stage",
"stringValue": "VALUE_CONVERTER"
},
{
"key": "__connect.errors.class.name",
"stringValue": "io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter"
},
{
"key": "__connect.errors.exception.class.name",
"stringValue": "org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException"
},
{
"key": "__connect.errors.exception.message",
"stringValue": "Converting byte[] to Kafka Connect data failed due to serialization error of topic test_topic: "
},
{
"key": "__connect.errors.exception.stacktrace",
"stringValue": "org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Converting byte[] to Kafka Connect data failed due to serialization error of topic test_topic: \n\tat io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter.toConnectData(JsonSchemaConverter.java:119)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.Converter.toConnectData(Converter.java:87)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.lambda$convertAndTransformRecord$3(WorkerSinkTask.java:500)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:166)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:200)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:142)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertAndTransformRecord(WorkerSinkTask.java:500)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:475)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:330)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:233)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:202)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:200)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:255)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)\nCaused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing JSON message for id -1\n\tat io.confluent.kafka.serializers.json.AbstractKafkaJsonSchemaDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaJsonSchemaDeserializer.java:176)\n\tat io.confluent.kafka.serializers.json.AbstractKafkaJsonSchemaDeserializer.deserializeWithSchemaAndVersion(AbstractKafkaJsonSchemaDeserializer.java:231)\n\tat io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter$Deserializer.deserialize(JsonSchemaConverter.java:165)\n\tat io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter.toConnectData(JsonSchemaConverter.java:108)\n\t... 17 more\nCaused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Unknown magic byte!\n\tat io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDe.getByteBuffer(AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDe.java:250)\n\tat io.confluent.kafka.serializers.json.AbstractKafkaJsonSchemaDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaJsonSchemaDeserializer.java:111)\n\t... 20 more\n"
}

---

This is my topic schema:

[image]

Can anyone help me to solve this error?

Thanks in advance,
Gianluca

Comment: this looks like it failed long before it got to Salesforce.  Have you tried the Kafka community for assistance?

Comment: Hi @cropredy, thank you very much for the advice! I have not tried, unfortunately there is no much documentation on this kind of connectors, so I hope to find some examples on the community!